# GAE Image service change root path

Tags: image, google-app-engine, service, path

I would like to know if it is possible to change dynamic image service root path instead of accessing image like this http://your_app_id.appspot.com/randomStringImageId i would like to access it by http://your_app_id.appspot.com/i/randomStringImageId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that's just an example.  Actual urls created by get_serving_url() run off of one of google's domains, they tend to look more like:

http://lh1.ggpht.com/xpRnv7oOGXWKZzNZ1PqOiAz5s1cnA0Nd6dycoiwojULlMNK8ziqb9G_jc8kpD0IGewcFOrxJwBS04m23u2X9oPA

And no, you can't modify them.

However, you can write your own handler at http://your_app_id.appspot.com/i/ to redirect the requests to the actual image URL.